# Given N equal circles (possibly overlapping) and M points on a plane. Find a circle which contains maximum number of points

Tags: algorithm, hash

Picture below shows a simple case. Circle 1 is the winner, because it contains points [1, 2, 5] -- more then any other circle.

[image]

Naive implementation which checks every point against every circle gives Time Limit.
"Use hash" they say. But where?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int64_t dist(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    int64_t dx = p1.x - p2.x; 
    int64_t dy = p1.y - p2.y;
    
    return dx*dx + dy*dy;
}

int main() 
{
    int circle_num;
    cin >> circle_num;
    
    vector<Point>   circles(circle_num);
    vector<int64_t> count  (circle_num);
    
    for (Point& p : circles)
        cin >> p.x >> p.y;
        
    int points_num;
    cin >> points_num;

    while (points_num--)
    {
        Point p;
        cin >> p.x >> p.y;
        
        for (int i = 0; i != circle_num; ++i)
        {
            if (dist(p, circles[i]) <= 400)
                ++count[i];
        }
    }
    
    int     index     = 0;
    int64_t max_count = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i != circle_num; ++i)
    {
        if (count[i] > max_count)
        {
            max_count = count[i];
            index     = i; 
        }
    }
    
    cout << (index + 1) << endl;
}
```

Possible input:

```
3 // number of circles
-1 0 // circle 1 center
1 0  // circle 2 center
2 5  // circle 3 center
3 // number of points
10 0 
20 0
22 5
```

Output: 3 -- circle 3 contains the most number of points

Comment: Interesting question. A usual trick for situations dealing with "close points in a plane" is to store the points in a [quad-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), so that when looking for points which are within a circle center, you only need to examine the branches of the quadtree that are close to that point. This can speed up the evaluation a lot as you avoid examining points which are known to be too far from the circle center.

Comment: That being said, I don't really know what algorithm they were thinking about when they told you to use hashes.

Comment: Where is this from? Can we test there as well? What are the limits for N and M?

Comment: Map related stuff. N ~ 10^4, M ~ 10^6. Space partitioning works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the circles are all the same size (800 units), a practical approach is to divide the plane into a grid, with each square 401x401 units, and use a hash from (x,y) -> list to collect the points in each square.

Then for each circle, just check the points in the up to 9 squares that it overlaps.

Comment: Dividing the plane into a grid is great, but I don't really see the point of the hash. What are you hashing? It looks to me like you simply have a 2d array of lists.

Comment: The size of the 2d array could be ((max_int-min_int)/200)^2